# RestServer in Codeigniter: 401 Unauthorized response when loading in view

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-restserver

I'm using the restserver in Codeigniter from Chris Kacerguis and I setup rest_auth with session.
When I'm logged in, I access the page whose view.php get the response through *file_get_contents* and it's returning 401 Unauthorized. 
When I access the API's direct page in a new tab, it returns the json correctly.

the *view.php* is loading the API content in this way:

```
json_decode(file_get_contents('https://example.com/api/proces/'), true);
```

the response:

> A PHP Error was encountered
>
> Severity: Warning
>
> Message: file_get_contents( *I needed to remove the link* ): failed to open >stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized

What's happening?

Comment: Does the api require any kind of authentication?

Answer (score 0):

I see your example url is using "https" and it is possible that your Apache / Nginx server is not configured correctly to handle the SSL in this way, but it would work fine with the certificate in the browser.

I would suggest you use curl as an alternative instead.

```
json_decode(curl_get_contents('https://example.com/api/process/'));
```

from here https://github.com/zg/curl_get_contents

Or of course you could use curl directly.

```
$url = 'https://example.com/api/process/';
$request = curl_init();
curl_setopt($request, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($request, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($request, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
$data = curl_exec($request);
curl_close($request);
```

Comment: I tried you sugestion but it didnt work. I tried others I found on the web but none worked. So I will setup off authentication for a while, and if I eventually find a solution, I will post it here.